# Empty a specific folder in every subdirectory

Tags: linux, directory, command, rm

When entering data in my filesystem, some files got into the wrong directory and now I have to reset all of the folders with a specific name, without touching the files in the other folders of that subdirectory. Since all of the directories I want to empty **have the same name** I assume that this is possible, unfortunately I dont really know how to do that.

I have following structure:

```
dir

   subdir1

       folder_I_want_to_empty   //all of these folders have the same name

           file_that_needs_to_be_deleted.txt

       folder_I_do_not_want_to_empty   

           file_that_has_to_remain.txt

   subdir2

       folder_I_want_to_empty   //all of these folders have the same name

           file_that_needs_to_be_deleted.txt

       folder_I_do_not_want_to_empty

           file_that_has_to_remain.txt 

   subdir3

       folder_I_want_to_empty   //all of these folders have the same name

           file_that_needs_to_be_deleted.txt

       folder_I_do_not_want_to_empty

           file_that_has_to_remain.txt
```

How can I empty **folder_I_want_to_empty** in every directory via the command prompt without deleting the folders or deleting any data from **folder_I_do_not_want_to_empty**?

Comment: Do you know that name of every file you want to delete or files that you want to keep?

Comment: I'm really curious about the usage of the words "folder" and "directory".  I typically use "folder" to refer to a gui artifact, and "directory" to refer to objects in a filesystem.  Are you using "folder" to mean a directory which contains only links to regular files?

Comment: @WilliamPursell I wasn't really thinking about it when I asked the question. I use "folder" when it's a "final" directory that doesn't contain any subdirectories. Probably just a bad translation in my head since Im not a native speaker. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
rm -fr */folder_I_want_to_empty/* */folder_I_want_to_empty/.??*
```

Please note that this command is very destructive and does not prompt but instead removes non-interactively without mercy.

If you wish to see what would be deleted, replace `rm -fr` by `ls -ld`:

```
ls -ld */folder_I_want_to_empty/* */folder_I_want_to_empty/.??*
```

Small print: Due to the pattern used above there is a very small chance that files or folders with only two characters, the first one being a dot `.` are not deleted. If this is a problem for you let us know in a comment and I will adjust the pattern.

Comment: The command worked, thanks alot! All of the file names are generated with the uniqid() function of php, thus the two character issue wasn't a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd probably do it.  for my example, I set up directory /test to use for testing.

```
find /test -type d -iname folder_I_want_to_empty -print0 | xargs -0 -I % find % -type f -print -delete
```

First, I `find` the directories (`-type d`) called `folder_I_want_to_empty`.  Then for each of those, I have xargs run a find for files within that directory, print their names, and delete them.  This doesn't delete subdirectories under `folder_I_want_to_empty` but it could be made to do so; in your example there aren't any.

Here's an example dockerfile to make this reproducible by readers:

```
FROM debian
RUN mkdir -p /test
WORKDIR /test
RUN mkdir -p subdir1/folder_I_want_to_empty subdir2/folder_I_want_to_empty subdir1/folder_I_do_not_want_to_empty subdir2/folder_I_do_not_want_to_empty && \
    find /test -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I % touch %/test1 %/test2
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh" ]
CMD [ "-c" , "find /test -type d -iname folder_I_want_to_empty -print0 | xargs -0 -I % find % -type f -print -delete; find /test -type f" ]
```